# How to count and display points in a pong game within C#?

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble counting the points of my AI Paddle Player and the user Paddle Player each time they miss colliding the ball. I tried using a boolean method and loops to count points, but to no avail as the program keeps on stating that the label in which my points are to be displayed, is "stack overflowed" due to an infinite loop which I am unable to recognize. So can you please help me.

Here is my code:

```
    private void resetShiruken()
    {
        if ((reset ==  false) && (AIPoints < MAXPoints))
        {
            picShiruken.Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2 - picShiruken.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2 - picShiruken.Height / 2); //puts the picShiruken Picturebox in the middle anytime the picPlayerPaddle or picAIPaddle miss and is useful for counting the points of the computer and the player.
            reset = true;
        }
        TheWinner();
   }


  private void TheWinner()
    {
        while (reset == true)
        {
                AIPoints += 1;
                reset = false;

        }
        if (AIPoints >= AIPoints)
        {
            lblAIPoints.Text = AIPoints.ToString();
        }
        resetShiruken();
    }
```

. resetShiruken() is a method that resets the ball to the middle each time any player misses.

. TheWinner() is a method that determines the winner of the game after either one of the players reach 5 points.

Thank You very Much,

Kai

Comment: `TheWinner` calls `resetShiruken` and `resetShiruken` calls `TheWinner` - there is your infinite loop

Comment: `TheWinner()` calls `resetShiruken()`. `resetShiruken()` calls `TheWinner()`. `TheWinner()` calls `resetShiruken()`. `resetShiruken()` calls `TheWinner()`. `TheWinner()` calls `resetShiruken()`. `resetShiruken()` calls `TheWinner()`.......

Comment: Note: An "infinite loop" and an "infinite recursion" are two different things.  You have an infinite recursion.  Nothing to do with loops.  Also note that the stack trace from your Stack Overflow Exception will tell you the problem.  Looking at your stack trace you would see that your two methods endlessly invoke each other.

Answer (score 2):

As comments says:

you have recursive call of methods which lasts forever. `resetShiruken` calls `TheWinner` which calls `resetShiruken` and so on....

```
    private void resetShiruken()
    {
        if ((reset ==  false) && (AIPoints < MAXPoints))
        {
            picShiruken.Location = new Point(ClientSize.Width / 2 - picShiruken.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2 - picShiruken.Height / 2); //puts the picShiruken Picturebox in the middle anytime the picPlayerPaddle or picAIPaddle miss and is useful for counting the points of the computer and the player.
            reset = true;
        }
        TheWinner();
   }


  private void TheWinner()
    {
        while (reset == true)
        {
                AIPoints += 1;
                reset = false;

        }
        if (AIPoints >= AIPoints)
        {
            lblAIPoints.Text = AIPoints.ToString();
        }
        //resetShiruken();  <--- if you get rid of that call, should be fine.
    }
```

Please note if you need to do `reset` after show the Winner, you should add additional parameter to reset method, or create separated method for post-winning reset.

Answer (score 0):

### Regular answer:

Your functions keep calling each other. Thats probably where the overflow is coming from.

From the functions given I'm unable to deduce exactly what your program flow would look like so I can't provide you with a fix which will do what you expect it to do.

To get rid of the overflow however simply remove either the call to "TheWinner" from "resetShiruken" or remove the call to "resetShiruken" from "TheWineer".

I suspect you should remove the latter.

---

### Code style:

You're mixing upercase and lowercase function names which is a bad habit.
The default case for method names is "PascalCase" in c# (as depicted by [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)).